# Change interface name

Tags: network-interface, networkmanager, interface

I'm with **NetworkManager**

I want to change the interface name, what I don't know sure the steps....

First I should know my **interface name** and **mac** from it,

```
ip a
```

Seconds, set down the interface,

```
sudo ip link set dev enp31s0 down
```

rename the device name, I'll change to **hallo0**.

First:

What is the difference between used,

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

and write on this file

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug  hallo0
iface hallo0 inet dhcp
```

Second:

With **udev**

```
sudo /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

and write on this file,

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="hallo0"
```

What from the two possibilities should use?

Can someone help with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was when to tried this steps the interface name not to change.

I found the problem because of it not change...

I did **Two** mistakes;

**1** - I forget to link the file,

```
sudo /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

I does it with

```
sudo  ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/70-net-setup-link.rules
```

**2** - Since **Ubuntu 16.04** and **Linux Mint 17** on the file,

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

where i write,

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="hallo0"
```

I had to write **without** the word **KERNEL=="eth*"**, so, I should to write,

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff", NAME="hallo0"
```

As [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/785442) to say.

For my question *what from the two possibilities should use?*, i to use **both**, because with the file **/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules**   I to say what **interface name** I`ll to chage and what **mac adress** belong to it....

The file `sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces`, you not need to change, you can leave it as is.